# copy 1 div content to another page div using javascript

Tags: javascript

hello guys I am developing a form at run time and appending the elements inside  div .

But while coping content of the div to another page it is not showing anything as if nothing got appended . can u tell me what is the problem...

https://jsfiddle.net/a80xyep8

```
<form>

    <div class="dynamicInput" id="dynamicInput">
        /*all dynamic elements are appended here as per javascript coding . but not showing in another page only static things are showing shuch as
        <input type="text" name="a" /> */
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit_form" onclick="f();" />
</form>

<script>
    var counterText = 0;
    var counterRadioButton = 0;
    var counterCheckBox = 0;
    var counterTextArea = 0;
    var lb = "";
    var name = "";

    function addAllInputs(divName, itemName) {

        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        switch (itemName) {
            case 'text':
                lb = prompt("enter label name");
                name = prompt("enter name for div attribute");
                //newdiv.innerHTML = " "+(counterText + 1)+ " "+ lb + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
                newdiv.innerHTML = " " + lb + " <br><input type='text'>";
                newdiv.setAttribute("id", name);
                newdiv.setAttribute("name", name);
                counterText++;
                document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                break;
            case 'radio':
                {
                    var n = prompt("How many number of elements do you need");
                    lb = prompt("enter label name");

                    newdiv.innerHTML = " " + lb + "<br>";
                    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        var newdiv1 = document.createElement('div');
                        lb = prompt("enter label name");
                        name = prompt("enter name for div attribute");
                        newdiv1.innerHTML = " " + lb + "<input type='radio'>";
                        newdiv1.setAttribute("id", name);
                        newdiv1.setAttribute("name", name);
                        counterRadioButton++;
                        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv1);
                    }
                    counterRadioButton++;
                    break;
                }

            case 'checkbox':
                var n = prompt("How many number of elements do you need");
                if (n == 1) {
                    lb = prompt("enter label name");
                    name = prompt("enter name for div attribute");
                    newdiv.innerHTML = " " + lb + " <br><input type='checkbox' >";
                    newdiv.setAttribute("id", name);
                    newdiv.setAttribute("name", name);
                    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                    counterCheckBox++;
                } else if (n > 1) {
                    var newdiv1 = document.createElement('div');
                    lb = prompt("enter label name");
                    newdiv1.innerHTML = " " + lb;
                    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv1);
                    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        var newdiv1 = document.createElement('div');
                        lb = prompt("enter label name");
                        name = prompt("enter name for div attribute");
                        newdiv1.innerHTML = " " + lb + " <br><input type='checkbox'>";
                        newdiv.setAttribute("id", name);
                        newdiv.setAttribute("name", name);
                        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv1);
                        counterCheckBox++;
                    }
                }

                break;

            case 'textarea':
                lb = prompt("enter label name");
                name = prompt("enter name for div attribute");
                newdiv.innerHTML = " " + lb + " <br><textarea>type here...</textarea>";
                newdiv.setAttribute("id", name);
                newdiv.setAttribute("name", name);
                counterTextArea++;
                document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                break;


                //document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
            case 'combobox':
                lb = prompt("enter label name");
                name = prompt("enter name for div attribute");
                newdiv.innerHTML = " " + lb + " <br><select id='combo[]'>type here...</select>";
                document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                var textb = lb;
                var combo = document.getElementById("combo");
                newdiv.setAttribute("id", name);
                newdiv.setAttribute("name", name);
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = textb.value;
                option.value = textb.value;
                try {
                    combo.add(option, null); //Standard 
                } catch (error) {
                    combo.add(option); // IE only
                }
                textb.value = "";
                document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: source code....  https://jsfiddle.net/a80xyep8/

Comment: I am coping using this method  page 1................................<script>  function f()
    {
    var pageContent = document.getElementById("dynamicInput").innerHTML; 
    sessionStorage.setItem("page1content", pageContent);
     window.location="file:///F:/vit5%20sem/form.html";
    }</script>

Comment: page 2   .... <script>
document.getElementById("copy").innerHTML=sessionStorage.getItem("page1content");
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wait for the DOM to be ready:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        document.getElementById("copy").innerHTML=sessionStorage.getItem("page1content");
    } )
</script>
```

Using you code in this way it worked for me perfectly.